# use ARC library in non arc project

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am developing an IOS application. I don't use ARC, my project is non ARC project. Bu I'm using a library developed for the ARC. This librar is [AFImagePager](https://github.com/gauravverma/AFImagePager). This librar is image gallery. So I added a flag What is -fobjc-arc at required file. But when running the application gives memory error. Memory usage is constantly increasing, not decreasing at all. Is this normal

Comment: What did the profiler said about the memory allocations? Who's responsible?

Comment: y u didnt use ARC. it is simple you dont have to worry about memory management

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to enable ARC for your project, using ARC isn't just a matter of adding -fobjc-arc, it's more involved than that.

The only thing that you can't do if you use a library that is ARC, is use GC, because that's not compatible.

If your project was MRR and working fine, continue to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For your application, make sure you are doing proper memory management. That is the only thing that I can think of that might be causing those errors. Tip: go to **Product -> Analyze…** and check on all the memory issues it reports.